# How large can a "recovery" like TWRP be?

Tags: recovery-mode, twrp, clockworkmod-recovery

Perhaps someone can correct my understanding.

1. True or false: TWRP is copied into the "recovery" directory and can be executed after reboot.
2. True or false: Running TWRP does not require an unlocked bootloader. (If so, why not?)
3. True or false: The size of a program such as TWRP is limited only by the size of the partition it is being copied into, and could be quite large.
4. True or false: An entire OS could in theory be run as a "recovery" if it were so desired.

Comment: You're right, TWRP is a custom recovery which is based on specific device recovery so its size would be the same as the recovery  partition

Comment: How large is that partition generally?

Answer (score 3):

1. False. Many newer devices utilizing the A/B partition layout don't have a dedicated `recovery` partition. See [landing page for Google Pixel](https://twrp.me/google/googlepixel.html) for a full explanation.
2. True. Certain devices have exploits that allow recovery on locked bootloaders - this kind of recovery is often referred to as "Safestrap". Do note "exploits" - most devices don't have such discovered.
3. True - partition size is usually the same as `boot`. On my Xiaomi Mi Mix 2, both are 67108864 bytes, i.e. 64MB.
4. True - recovery can be considered a minimal OS by itself (with complete display, input, file management subsystems). If you want to start a regular OS by booting into `recovery`, just flash a regular boot image (one that usually goes into `boot`) to `recovery`.

Comment: +1 last point - TWRP by itself can be considered as bare bone OS in addition to letting you boot into one